# Append DOM element containing php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento

I need to append a DOM element to another using javascript or jQuery, and this DOM element has to contain a translatable string using PHP like so:

```
<?php echo $this->__("submit"); ?>
```

I tried something like:

```
var string = '<?php echo $this->__("submit"); ?>';
jQuery('.my-element').append('<span>' + string + '</span>');
```

But the php part is rendered as plain text. Is there a way to accomplish something like that?

Comment: PHP runs on the server, not the client.

Comment: Should there be a quote and close bracket in `'</span>;`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: So long as you execute that JS logic within a `.php` page, it will work. If you place it in a `.js` file it won't as the PHP won't be interpreted. The alternatives would be to output the PHP to a hidden element in the DOM, then clone it when needed, or to make an AJAX request and return the required HTML from your PHP code on the server.

Comment: *«But the php part is rendered as plain text. »* --> Yes... How else do you expect it to be rendered?

Comment: I just needed to try and see i guess :)